# Can't import bacpac file from Azure to Local SqlServer 2012

Tags: sql-server, azure

I exported a bacpac from Azure SQL Database and am trying to import it on my local environment.

It works perfectly on my development machine running SQLServer 2016, but if I try and install it on a server running SQLServer 2012, I get a compatibility issue.

'A project which specifies Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with SQL Server 2014'

It is definitely not any of my stored procs/tables etc as it is not using anything specific to newer SQL databases.

I am using the latest SSMS and have also tried installing some of the Data Tier application hot fixes that some people have mentioned, but no joy.

Comment: You could import the azure sql db to a sql db project via visual studio, then publish to local db.

Comment: Why would I even need to do that though when it is such a basic database? Has MS changed some versioning that is preventing the migration?